# kendoui Grid with autocomplete on its toolbar?

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Update:**
I tried and spent alot of my time fixing the issue, and at last problem solved.
But initially Many Thanks to OnaBai and to my colleague who helped to come this far.

Now i am stuck here.

I type username and it show display on dropdown and after pressing TAB or ENTER it show the result in grid.
The result is only shown in grid if it is from page "1", but if it is from page "2" or any other further page the result is not shown.

Here is how it is working:
[image]

but when if i search for other user which is not on page 1 then it dont show display the other user in grid. instead i get empty grid.
[image]

**FireBug screenShots:**
[image]
[image]

Here is my Updated Code after i did some more changes in the code.:

```
  <?php
/*foreach($users_list_data->result() as $row){
    echo $row->Username."<br />";
}*/
?>

<div id="grid"></div>
    <div id="details" />
    <div class="second_column_content_container">
    </div>



<script>

function create_user() {

    var entryform = $("#insert_user_info");
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/user_management/manage_users/createUser',
        data : entryform.serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            $(".second_column").html(response);
        }
    });
}

function create_user_form() {


    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/user_management/manage_users/load_user_form',

        success : function(response) {
            $(".second_column").html(response);
        }
    });
}

function onChange(arg) {



        var selected = "";
        var grid = this;

        grid.select().each(function() {
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
            selected = dataItem.Username;
        });

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user_management/manage_users/get_user_groups/"+selected,

        beforeSend: function(){


            $("#pre_image").attr("src","http://localhost/zorkif_new/images/pre.gif");

        },

        success: function(output_string) {


            $('.data_column_a').html(output_string);

        }
    });
 }


    var wnd, detailsTemplate;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var serverBaseUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:{
                serverPaging: true,
                transport: {
                    read: serverBaseUrl + "index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/",
                    update: {
                        url: serverBaseUrl + "index.php/user_management/manage_users/userUpdate/",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
//                    destroy: {
//                        url: serverBaseUrl + "index.php/user_management/manage_users/userDelete/",
//                        dataType: "jsonp"
//                    }
                    //update: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/"
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e.responseText);
                },
                schema:{
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total",
                    model: {
                        id: "UserID",
                        fields: {
                            FirstName: { editable: true },
                            LastName: { validation: { required: true} },
                            MiddleNames:{validation:{required:true}}
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize:5

            },
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#toolbarTemplate").html()),
            scrollable: true,

            selectable: "row",
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "UserID",
                    hidden:true
                },
                {
                    field: "Username",
                    title:"Username"
                },
                { field: "FirstName",
                    title:"First Name"
                },
                {field:"MiddleNames"},
                {field:"LastName"},
                {field:"City"},
                {field:"Email"},
                //{field:"Actions"},
                //{command: { text: "Delete", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"},
                {command: { text: "Details", click: redirectToPage }, title: " ", width: "140px" },
                { command: { text: "Edit", click: redirectToEditPage }, title: "&nbsp;", width: "140px" }
            ],
            change: onChange,
            editable: "popup"
        });
        $("#users").kendoAutoComplete({
            minLength: 3,
            dataTextField: "Username",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: serverBaseUrl + "index.php/user_management/manage_users/search_user/",
                        data: function (arg){
                            //alert(arg);
                            //alert({Username:autocompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value});
                               return {Username : $("#users").data("kendoAutoComplete").value()};
                            //return $("#users").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            change: onChangeAutoComplete
        });

        function onChangeAutoComplete(){
            var value = this.value();
            var grid = $('#grid');
            if (value) {
                grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "Username", operator: "Contains", value: value });
            } else {
                grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
            }
        }
        /*$("#users").kendoAutoComplete({
            minLength: 3,
            dataTextField: "Title",
            //JSON property name to use
            dataSource: {
                pageSize: 10,
                //Limits result set
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/echo/json/",
                        //using jsfiddle echo service to simulate JSON endpoint
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            // /echo/json/ echoes the JSON which you pass as an argument
                            json: JSON.stringify([
                                {
                                    "Title": "Doctor Who: The Trial of a Time Lord"},
                                {
                                    "Title": "Doctor Who: The Key to Time"},
                                {
                                    "Title": "Doctor Who: The Time Meddler"},
                                {
                                    "Title": "Doctor Who: The End of Time"}
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });*/

        /*change: function () {
                var value = this.value();
                if (value) {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "UserID", operator: "eq", value: value });
                } else {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
                }
            }
        });*/
        /*$("#users").blur(function() {
            var data = $(this).data("kendoAutoComplete").dataSource._data,
                    nbData = data.length,
                    found = false;

            for(var iData = 0; iData < nbData; iData++) {
                if(this.value === data[iData].Title)
                    found = true;
            }
            console.log(found);
        });*/

        wnd = $("#details").kendoWindow({
                    title: "Customer Details",
                    modal: true,
                    visible: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 300
                }).data("kendoWindow");
        detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

    });

    function redirectToPage(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
            success: function(output_string){
                $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);
                //$('.second_column_content_container').innerHTML("hello");
                //alert(output_string);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
    function redirectToEditPage(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/edit_user/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
            success: function(output_string){
                $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);
                //$('.second_column_content_container').innerHTML("hello");
                //alert(output_string);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
        //show details on a popup
       function showDetailsPopup(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
        wnd.center().open();
    }

    //This will redirect to Next Page
    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
            success: function(data){
                alert("done");
                //$('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);
                //$('.second_column_content_container').innerHTML("hello");
                //alert(output_string);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("error");
            }
        });


        //var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        //alert(JSON.parse(item.UserID));
        //window.location.href="http://www.google.com/";



    }
</script>
        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
                <div id="details-container">
                    <h2>#= FirstName #</h2>
                    <h2>City: #= City # </h2>
                </div>
        </script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="toolbarTemplate">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <label class="category-label" for="users">Search Users: </label>
        <input type="text" id="users" style="width: 250px;" />
    </div>
</script>

<div class="data_column_a">
    <img src=""  id="pre_image" >
</div>
```

Now how to solve this very extremely difficult problem  O_o??

---

Update:
This Username is on Page 2 of the Grid as can be seen in ScreenShot.
[image]

But during Search, it sends the headers of page 1 when i search for username that is other than of page 1.

[image]

Banging my head to walls, How to Solve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to you `autocomplete` definition that is not sending any `Username` argument on `read`. Try defining `transport.read` as:

```
transport     : {
    read    : {
        url : "search_user.php",
        data: function (arg) {
            return {Username : autocompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value()};
        }
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type    : "POST"
},
```

**EDIT**: For applying selected value on `autocomplete` as filtering condition for the grid. You should do:

```
var autocompleteUsers = $("#users").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Username",
    dataSource   : {
        severFiltering: true,
        transport     : {
            read    : {
                url : "search_user.php",
                data: function (arg) {
                    return {Username: autocompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value()};
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type    : "POST"
        }
    },
    change       : function () {
        var username = autocompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
        var filter = {
            logic  : "and",
            filters: [
                {
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    field     : "Username",
                    value     : username,
                    operator  : "startswith"
                }
            ]
        };
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(filter);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have modified the code and it works, but now the problem is when i type something in textbox, the grid filters correctly but when the item is in page 2 or another age(for example), the filtering on a grid doesn't work, I only see an empty grid.

Comment: Would you mind explaining-me what are you trying to achieve? Is it filtering `grid` content by `username` but using an `autocomplete` instead of grid columns header?

Comment: yes, exactly, i have a textbox where an autocomplete pops up and filter the grid accordingly but this only works for the first page i.e for the first items that is displayed in the grid. If i search for the item i.e which is the next page (page 2) of the grid, the grid filters but data is empty in the grid

Comment: Please see this Image:
http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/pakistanihaider/emptygrid_zpse302da16.jpg?t=1364905389
Data is coming from db and shown in dropdown but when clicked empty grid is shown cuz data is on other page.

Comment: and in this image when result is clicked the result is shown in the grid cuz that user is in the first page of the gird.
http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/pakistanihaider/page1_zpsf0cab2a0.jpg?t=1364905407

Comment: @OnaBai
Sir, i updated my question, only one last issue remaining related to this autocomplete with Grid.
Please can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: You are mixing incompatible concepts. When you say `serverPaging` you ask the server to do the paging and as consequence it only transfers the number of records that you asked for. When you **do not** say `serverFiltering` you say that Kendo UI will filter the data from what it has in memory (one page in your case) so you cannot find data in second page. In addition I cannot see where are you filtering data, why are you not using `dataSource.filter` for filtering those records that match the `username` typed in `autocomplete`?

Comment: @OnaBai
Sir, i have used `serverFiltering: true,`.
Maybe i have used it wrong place.
Can you please point to code where and how to fix the filtering.
I want to be continued with server filtering for better performance.

Comment: You have in `autocomplete` but should define it too in `grid` since this is the data that you want to filter.

Comment: Check **EDIT** in my answer on how to filter `grid` data with `autocomplete` value.

Comment: @OnaBai
Sir, i have applied your way..
But now the grid showing all the data of first page only, not specific data as it used to show?
it only happens if i apply 'serverFiltering: true,'.
Please see the image.
http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/pakistanihaider/serverFiltering_zps50be230c.jpg?t=1364965897

Comment: if the username belongs to other page then still grid sends the headers for page 1?

Comment: @OnaBai
Sir i uploaded two more screenshots in my question regarding this serverpaging problem.